# Best way to optimize query while searching string in big sentences

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I have requirement as below

> poem belongs to poet
>
> poet has many poems

If user searching for word "ruby"

It should give,

> Total number of times word ruby used in all poems.
>
> Show all the poems which has the word ruby.
>
> Number of times word ruby used in each poems.
>
> Total number of poets used the word ruby.
>
> Total number of times each poets used the word ruby.

So my query in model Poem is here

```
    poems= where("poem_column like ?", "%#{word}%" )
    @results = {}
    poems.each do |poem|
      words = poem.poem_column.split
      count = 0
      words.each do |word|
        count += 1 if word.upcase.include?(word.upcase)
      end
      @results[poem] = count # to get each poem using word ruby
    end
```

And to get poets count
in Poem Model

```
   @poets = poems.select("distinct(poet_id)")
      @poets.each do |poet|
        @poets_word_count << poems.where("poet_id = #{poem.poet_id}").count
      end
```

Where poems are around 50k. its taking almost more than 1 minute.
I know am doing in wrong way but i couldnt optimize it in any other way.

i think the below lines taking too much time as it looping each words of all poems.

```
      words.each do |word|
        count += 1 if word.upcase.include?(word.upcase)
      end
```

Can anyone of you show me the way to optimize it.As lack of knowledge in queries i couldnt do it in any other way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you know where is taking the most time: getting poets? getting number of occurrences for the searched word inside poem_column?

Comment: Both taking time but  searched word inside poem_column taking more.[poem column contains up to 20 lines]

Comment: Consider using [SQLite3 Full Text Search](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not an answer, just a test.**

First, reduce the data extracting keywords for each poem as they are saved:

```
rails g resource Keyword word occurrences poem_id:integer
rails db:migrate
```

Then in your Poem model:

```
# add more words
EXCLUDED_WORDS = %w( the a an so that this these those )

has_many :keywords

before_save :set_keywords

# { :some => 3, :word => 2, :another => 1}
def keywords_hash(how_many = 5)
  words = Hash.new 0
  poem_column.split.each do |word|
    words[word] += 1 if not word.in? EXCLUDED_WORDS
  end
  Hash[words.sort { |w, w1| w1 <=> w }.take(how_many)]
end

def set_keywords
  keywords_hash.each do | word, occurrences |
    keywords.create :word => word, :occurrences => occurrences
  end
end
```

In `Keyword` model:

```
belongs_to :poem

def self.poem_ids
  includes(:poem).map(&:poem_id)
end

def self.poems
  Poem.where(id: poem_ids)
end
```

Then when you have word to search for:

```
keywords = Keyword.where(word: word)
poems = keywords.poems
poets = poems.poets
```

To use this last part, you would need in `Poem` model:

```
def self.poet_ids
  includes(:poet).map(&:poet_id)
end

def self.poets
  Poet.where(id: poet_ids)
end
```

As far as I see this way would require just 3 queries, no joins, so it seems to make sense.

I will think in how to extend this way to search by the entire content.

Comment: the only thing is database issue, as we have to store info of each words or else its really reduced time. thanks and cheers

Again the Keywords table will have millions of data

Comment: SQLite full text search makes much more sense, in @LS_dev comment. I was about to suggest to switch to a more usual production DB and use full text search, like PostgreSQL and use `pg_search` gem.

Answer (score 0):

Im my opnion, you can change following code quoted from your post:

```
poems.each do |poem|
  words = poem.poem_column.split
  count = 0
  words.each do |word|
    count += 1 if word.upcase.include?(word.upcase)
  end
  @results[poem] = count # to get each poem using word ruby
end
```

to:

```
poems.each {|poem| @results[poem] = poem.poem_column.scan(/ruby/i).size}
```

Comment: it doesnt make any diferences :-(